# How to transfer from paper wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

Can someone help me. I jut don't know how to transfer Monero from a paper wallet.  I tried to down load the 64 bit wallet for windows but it will not sync.  What can I do? The wallet just won't sync.  It is stuck at 679 days behind and it has been two days now.

Comment: Can you give us few more details?

Comment: Use that ^ guide. If you need any assistance with the GUI in general, see: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/7hhgjx/monero_gui_01110_helium_hydra_megathread_download/

Comment: Is the paper wallet in the form of 25 Electrum words or the private spend key?  There are a few extra steps to convert a private spend key into 25 Electrum words used by numerous Monero applications to make a cold spend key hot.

Comment: i cannot get the wallet to sync.   Therefore I can't enter the seed. The wallet is showing 678 days behind continuously.

Comment: @steve - try to restart the wallet + daemon.

Comment: dEBRUYNE, I deleted the wallet yesterday.  what is meant by a restart and how is such done.  Thank You.